# Managing dependencies of Javascript libraries with Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Per [ember-cli managing dependencies](http://www.ember-cli.com/#managing-dependencies), 3rd party libraries, jQuery plugins, etc, should be installed via bower then included into Brocfile.js.  However, what if you have a custom jQuery plugin, or other Javascript library that is required that is not available via bower.

Should these non bower'fied plugins be placed into a different directory, IE not vendor/, then added to the Brocfile.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just manually include it in any directory and then `app.import` it from that directory.

But you should note that using bower you can install any file not just one thats in the bower repo.

for example you can do something like

```
bower install --save http://example.com/js/myjsfile.js
```

and in an ember-cli app bower would copy that file to `/vendor/js/myjsfile.js`
and you could then put `app.import('/vendor/js/myjsfile.js')` in your `Brocfile.js`